# Has and belongs to many association search in thinking sphinix rails 3.2.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using `Rails 3.2.14`, `thinking-sphinx 3.1.1` and `Sphinx 2.2.4-id64-release (r4806)`

I have two modals below:-

```
Album.rb
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres

Genre.rb
  has_and_belongs_to_many :albums
```

So the associated table is `albums_genres`

I want to search albums using the `genre_id`

`Example:` When I pass a `genre_id` then it should return all the albums associated to that `genre_id` on the basis of third table `albums_genres`

I have tried like that

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :album, :with => :active_record do
  #other indexes     
  has genres.id, :as => :genre_ids, :source => :query     
end
```

But when i run the rake task as `rake ts:index` i am getting the error as:-

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `join_table' for #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0x000000079224d8>
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/simple_many_query.rb:15:in `quoted_foreign_key'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/simple_many_query.rb:28:in `to_sql'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/property_query.rb:76:in `queries'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/simple_many_query.rb:5:in `to_s'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/property_query.rb:15:in `to_s'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/sphinx_presenter.rb:45:in `query'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/sphinx_presenter.rb:38:in `multi_declaration'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/attribute/sphinx_presenter.rb:23:in `declaration'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:96:in `block in append_presenter_to_attribute_array'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:93:in `each'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:93:in `append_presenter_to_attribute_array'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:132:in `prepare_for_render'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/sql_source.rb:65:in `render'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/riddle-1.5.11/lib/riddle/configuration/index.rb:29:in `block in render'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/riddle-1.5.11/lib/riddle/configuration/index.rb:29:in `collect'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/riddle-1.5.11/lib/riddle/configuration/index.rb:29:in `render'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/core/index.rb:53:in `render'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/riddle-1.5.11/lib/riddle/configuration.rb:43:in `block in render'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/riddle-1.5.11/lib/riddle/configuration.rb:43:in `collect'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/riddle-1.5.11/lib/riddle/configuration.rb:43:in `render'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:90:in `render'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:96:in `block in render_to_file'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:96:in `render_to_file'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:13:in `configure'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:24:in `index'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/shamsul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug with Rails 3.2, `:source => :query` and HABTM joins (which is sadly not surprising - getting the code to work even with Rails 4.0 was painful and fragile).

I'm afraid your options are either upgrade to Rails 4 or not use the `:source => :query` option (and I know that means you lose some nice speed gains for indexing).

Odds of me getting a patch sorted in the near future is small (but others are welcome to give it a shot, if they wish).